# why cookie is not getting set on my website

Tags: php, cookies

I want to set cookie after login on my website.

**following code works and set cookie**

```
setcookie('signinemail', $email, 0, '/');
```

**But following codes are not setting cookie**

```
setcookie( 'signinemail', $email, 0, '/', 'www.mydomain.com', isset($_SERVER["HTTPS"]), true);

setcookie( 'signinemail', $email, 0, '/', 'www.mydomain.com', true, true);

setcookie( 'signinemail', $email, 0, '/', '.mydomain.com', true, true);
```

when using `var_dump($_COOKIE);` ,with first code, cookie is seen as set but not with second code.

I am using PHP 7.1

Comment: why don't you just use the Session for this?

Comment: @ADyson I am using opencart in another folder and opencart does not use $_SESSION for its sessions but a session object. so need cookie

Comment: Cookies are editable by the visitor.. bad idea for login auth, if that is what you are doing

Comment: opencart has not reinvented session they have just WRAPPED `$_SESSION` in a class for ease of use

Comment: @Ron yes... you are right.. but I am surprised why second codes not working on my site. why secured cookies are not getting set...

Comment: @Ron  I want to use this cookie value to autofill email field in opencart login, user need to enter password... password will not be autofilled...

Comment: "a session object"....so use that, then. Or just use $_SESSION direct, it's still there.

Comment: @ADyson Yes.. I tried that and it worked when first code for setting cookies is used... But when I am using second codes, it is not working... because var_dump for second codes showing no cookie with name 'signinemail'..... I want to set secured cookies... but it is not working..

Comment: Are you trying to implement a "keep me signed in" feature?

Answer (score 0):

First of

```
setcookie
```

> which domain using? Try same url domain name

if using localhost ... set with localhost

> which server using? Try same server HTTP OR HTTPS

if using **https** set **true** else **false**

Try.

Comment: yes... same url domain name tried.. also site is https

Comment: yes... but unfortunatelly not working and I am searching for answer to it...